# don't want editable combobox to change itemssource

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a custom wpf ComboBox in which the ItemsSource is a long string list.

Special: The ItemsSource is filtered dynamically by the text in the ComboBox TextBox.
This means, the ItemsSource changes its ItemCount by throwing out the filtered strings.
But It never should change the string items themselves. But this is what happens:

To have a ComboBox which allows text input, i need to set

```
IsEditable='True'
```

Example: this is my ItemsSource:

```
Item1000
Item2000
Item3000
```

When I type "Item200", press return, it shows the item to select:

```
Item2000
```

when I don't select the item by mouse or up/down arrow, and press only return having typed "Item200", I have this ItemsSource the next time:

```
Item1000
Item200
Item3000
```

How can I prevent this behavior ?

I heard that in wpf, what is known in Winforms as "DropDownList"-Style, you can achieve by setting IsEditable=False.
But then, the ComboBox TextBox (which provides the filtering), won't be available, which is no option in my case. ?

Comment: Post the filtering code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..the answer is that I was overwriting some objects. I found out by the good hint from you!

Answer (score 1):

The intended behavior you're describing is an auto-complete box not a `ComboBox`. Try using a control that is actually designed to do what you need instead of working against a built in one that isn't. There are a lot of auto-complete implementations out there (Silverlight has it built in but WPF doesn't) that are freely available, for example: http://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/